# Google Cloud Storage cors policy allow-all

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to allow all origins using the following command:

```
gsutil cors set /tmp/cors.json gs://my_bucket
```

Would the proper json document be:

```
 [
    {
      "origin": ["*"]
    }
]
```

Or:

```
[
    {
      "origin": "*"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `"origin": ["*"]`.

The `origin` value is expected to be an array, even if you only want to specify a single origin or only the `*` wildcard. See, e.g., the example at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors#description.

Answer (score 24):

As reference,

1. Open the Google Cloud Shell, in the Cloud Console.

```
printf '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["*"],"method":
["GET","POST","HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 86400}]' > cors.json

gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<bucket_name>
```